# Database error on website

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, scada

I got this error trying to access our SCADA website:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 341
```

I scanned into the Loader.php file and on line 341 found this code: 
`$CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);`

This is the complete block with the error code:

```
public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL)
    {
        // Grab the super object
        $CI =& get_instance();

        // Do we even need to load the database class?
        if (class_exists('CI_DB') AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset($CI->db) AND is_object($CI->db))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB.php');

        if ($return === TRUE)
        {
            return DB($params, $active_record);
        }

        // Initialize the db variable.  Needed to prevent
        // reference errors with some configurations
        $CI->db = '';

        // Load the DB class
        $CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);
    }
```

Comment: The issue (likely) wont be in the loader but with your CI configuration in `application/config/database.php` are you sure the credentials set are correct?

Comment: We haven't changed anything anywhere. The website and everything was working fine and suddenly this morning it gave us this error.

Comment: Is your database server (service) still online?

Comment: Yes.
i just out that one of our team mates changed the password on codeignitor on phpmyadmin and now we dont remember what the old password was?
How do set the new password on my webserver? anyway i can do it?

Comment: I accessed the  'application/config/database.php' and found the password to be : $db['default']['password'] = 'e00864971d044f26353287c12af06441'; How do i decode this?

Comment: autoload database in config/autoload.php And show us yoru database settings from config/database.php

Answer (score 1):

The file you mention is just where the call happened when the issue happened.

The real issue is  either:

1. Your settings in `application/configuration/database.php`
   or
2. Your Database server is down, inaccessible or the credentials have changed

Comment: Yes as mentioned above, our team mate changed the password on codeignitor. and no one remembers what the old password was. Is there anyway we could reset the password on the application/configuration/database.php? because the password in there is all encoded so if i do change the password on phpmyadmin, i wouldnt know how to set it at the database.php file.

Comment: If you use version control yes, just revert, otherwise you have to login as the db root user and change the apps username's password

Comment: As this was the answer, please mark the question as answered